# statements about the continuity of functions on topologies

Tags: general-topology, continuity

> Let $(X,d_X),(Y,d_Y)$ be metric spaces and $T_X,T_Y$ be the topologies induced by $d_X$ and $d_Y$, respectively. Which of the following statements are true for $:(X,d_X)$ and $(Y,d_Y)$?
>
> I) If $f$ is continuous, then $T_X \subset\{f^{-1}(U)|U\in T_Y\}$
>
> II) If f is continuous, then $\{f^{-1}(U)|U\in T_Y\} \subset T_X$

The second one is obviously true, since it's basically the definition of continuity on topologies. The first one should be false, so I tried to think of a counterexample. But I can't find one. Could someone help me please?

Comment: $X=Y=\mathbb R$, $f(x)=x^2$

Comment: See my edits for proper MathJax usage. $(X,d_X) \to (U, d_Y)$ is proper usage; $(X,d_X) -> (Y, d_Y)$ is not. And {curly braces} should not be excluded from MathJax: $$ T_X \subset\{f^{-1}(U)\mid U\in T_Y\} $$ And notice the use of \mid. $\qquad$

Comment: @Cauchy Are you using the standard topology? Because if so, I don't understand your example

Comment: Yes standard topology. Is e.g. $(0,1) = f^{-1}(U)$ for some $U \subset Y$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A constant function whose domain is topologically nontrivial gives a simple counterexample to the first statement. This is because for a constant function all preimages are either the whole space or the empty set.